# Running mysql client with custom my.cnf

Tags: mysql, command-line-interface

I have an application which invokes the mysql client to run various tasks. For various reasons, mysql is invoked as the user who runs the application (this is central to the security model and would also affect functionality if changed). Currently the mysql username and password is passed to the client program via the command line - obviously this is not a desirable state of affairs.

Over-writing the $HOME/my.cnf file is not an ideal solution - there may be multiple, concurrent tasks running against different (local and/or remote) databases. The access to the databases must be authenticated.

Is there a way to pass a custom my.cnf file (or other way to securely pass the username and password) to the mysql client without having to simulate an interactive login?

(supplying a my.cnf file using --defaults-file or --defaults-extra-file results in `mysql: unknown variable 'username=my_db_user'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have tested this ?

```
$ cat .my.cnf
[client]
user=root
password=rootpw

$ mysql --defaults-file=/Pathtomycnf/.my.cnf

MariaDB [(none)]> quit
Bye
```

Comment: Thanks - yes problem was that I had 'username' instead of 'user' :)